# How to fix bad screen in MS-Access list?

Tags: forms, ms-access, screen

I developed an MS-Access solution. On some lists on some PCs the output is bad. I use on all PCs Windows 7 and Access 2010.

Some lines are not visible or only partly visible.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I think this is probably a problem with the graphic driver but all graphic drivers are up to date and standard drivers (Intel CPU with built in GPU).

When I scroll the list the bad lines are refreshed.

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Obviously I also tried to google this but it's difficult to find the right words like bad screen output or blank screen. Any ideas?

I write Access applications since many years and I never had a similar problem.

Comment: I have no solution other than looking for a hardware/driver issue. You could try to adjust the hardware acceleration setting. For a further search you could search using "render" or "rendering".

Comment: You could try turning off 'Use Windows-themed Controls on Forms'.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong. Why would you use continuous form? can't you use datasheet? continuous form draws too much and requires memory. Try datasheet and let us know the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, a short update: yesterday I worked a little longer on one of the problematic PCs. There are also other problems like Windows Explorer does not automatically update the file list and other screen related issues. It seems the Intel CPU with integrated GPU has no settings which I can change. In the next days I will put another graphic card into the PC to check if the problem still persists.  
Krish, I don’t use datasheet because a couple of the fields are calculated on the fly which I can’t do in a datasheet.